# How to get the second level key's of JSON using python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

Below is content of JSON file, how can I get only the keys of the second level, that means I should be able to store the keys like uid,passid,signbuttonid,logoIcon,cornerSettingMenu,logoutButtonId,overlayId,loaderInFunctionalPanel this keys I should be able to store in a list or some array using python. means I need like

```
list[0]=  uid

list[1]=passid

list[2]=  signbuttonid

list[3]=logoIcon and so on . . . . . .
```

> {
>         "GlobalElements" : 
>   [
>                *{
>                  "uid":"userEmail",
>                  "passid":"userPwd",
>                  "signbuttonid": "//button[@class='btn btn-mammoth']",
>                  "logoIcon":"//a[@class='logo text-hide']", 
>                  "cornerSettingMenu":"//div[@class='dropdown-toggle']/p",
>                  "logoutButtonId":"//a[@class='logout']",
>                  "overlayId":"//div[@class='overlay']",
>                  "loaderInFunctionalPanel":"//div[@class='small-inline-loader']/child::i[@class='fa
>   fa-spinner fa-pulse']"
>                }* ]

Note: I don't need values of that. I need only keys.

Can Anybody help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just get the keys from the second level dictionary with .keys() [python dictionary docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Comment: But it is giving whole uid,passid, singbuttonid so on, what I have to do if I need get only uid??

Comment: It gives you a list with the keys, like you wanted in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if

```
import json

a={ "GlobalElements" :[ { "uid":"userEmail", "passid":"userPwd", "signbuttonid": "//button[@class='btn btn-mammoth']", "logoIcon":"//a[@class='logo text-hide']", "cornerSettingMenu":"//div[@class='dropdown-toggle']/p", "logoutButtonId":"//a[@class='logout']", "overlayId":"//div[@class='overlay']", "loaderInFunctionalPanel":"//div[@class='small-inline-loader']/child::i[@class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse']" } ]}

a= json.dumps(a) #serialize dictionary to json

b=json.loads(a)  #unserialize json to get dictionary
```

get the list of keys with :

```
l= b["GlobalElements"][0].keys()
print l
```

> [u'uid', u'logoutButtonId', u'logoIcon', u'signbuttonid', u'passid', u'overlayId', u'loaderInFunctionalPanel', u'cornerSettingMenu']

Comment: Yes, this Helped me and using index like l[0],l[1] helped me, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
a={ "GlobalElements" :[ { "uid":"userEmail", "passid":"userPwd", "signbuttonid": "//button[@class='btn btn-mammoth']", "logoIcon":"//a[@class='logo text-hide']", "cornerSettingMenu":"//div[@class='dropdown-toggle']/p", "logoutButtonId":"//a[@class='logout']", "overlayId":"//div[@class='overlay']", "loaderInFunctionalPanel":"//div[@class='small-inline-loader']/child::i[@class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse']" } ]}

l= a["GlobalElements"][0].keys()
print l[0]
print l[1]
print l[2] so on or using for loop worked for me.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import json 
store your json content in a variable. if it is in a file, read the file and store it in variable.
Use dumps() and loads() method to serialize and unserialize and just take the values as below code

```
import json

x={ "GlobalElements" :[ { "uid":"userEmail", "passid":"userPwd", "signbuttonid": "//button[@class='some id']", "logoIcon":"//a[@class='some id']", "cornerSettingMenu":"//div[@class='dropdown-toggle']/p", "logoutButtonId":"//a[@class='logout']", "overlayId":"//div[@class='overlay']", "loaderInFunctionalPanel":"//div[@class='small-inline-loader']/child::i[@class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse']" }  ] }

x= json.dumps(x)

y=json.loads(y)
z= b["GlobalElements"][0].keys()
```

here `z` will be holding the first value of the second level.